# Why a user will see multiple language under language key in app store?

Tags: ios, app-store, itunes

I set the primary language as english in my account,when i push the app to app store.
After approving the app it is showing multiple language like English,Arabic,Danish,Dutch..
Please give me any solution to resolve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The languages you are offering for your application does not depend on your primary language which you set in your account, but in the number of localizations your app project contains.

When you open your project in Xcode, select the project name in the left panel (normally the first line of the tree view), the select the name of your project (not of your target), the select Info. You will find a section called "Localizations". Make sure that only English is available in the list. Then only English will be shown in the app store after you submitted it again.

Comment: Please find this link to see our project screenshot.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/na8x35z8c4hc6xi/Screen%20Shot%202017-01-19%20at%205.57.26%20PM.png?dl=0

Comment: Please reply me it is correct or not.Or i will add a new one

Comment: You screenshot does not show the setting I described in my answer. Please have a look the area I described.